# Mysqldump max_allowed_packet issue

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump

I need to migrate a database that was managed by someone who left the company.
The source server is MariaDB 1:10.5.5, the destination MariaDB 1:10.5.19.

The existing backup scripts use the following command:

mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=5120M -u root -p my_db > my_dump.sql

Both servers have the following settings
In /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf:

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
```

In /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:

`max_allowed_packet=524288000`  (-> = 500MB)

I don't know why but there must be a reason it was set like this.

I don't understand why using "--max_allowed_packet=5120M" on the command line.

It doesn't fit with the server settings and the MySQL documentation says that the mysqldump max_allowed_packet value must not exceed the server value and that the protocol has a max value of 1G.

If I run "mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=5120M -u root -p my_db > my_dump.sql" manually,

I get this warning:
"Warning: option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 5368709120 adjusted to 2147483648"

How can I dump this database safely? I need to be sure I don't loose any data and that it will import in the new server.
Do I have to use "max_allowed_packet"? Maybe with the same value as the server (524288000) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider upgrading in-place.  (No dump + restore)  But it would be good to take a backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as its less then the limit at both ends, and you don't have any very large blobs in your database that would exceed the packet size, you want lose data by using a smaller packet size or a different packet size at each end of the exchange.

Comment: Thank you. How to be sure there's no large blob in the DB? Would I get a warning or error during mysqldump if there was any?

Comment: yes, you'll get a warning.